# Get Properties of Generic Class That Is A Grouping

Tags: c#, generics, properties, typeof

I have the following code which gets all the properties that are of type string which is then used to filter the source against.

```
public IQueryable<T> FilterSource(IQueryable<T> source, string filter)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)).Select(x => x.Name);
}
```

My problem is that the source happens to be an `IGrouping`, so when I call `typeof(T).GetProperties()` I only get access to the grouping keys. Whereas I need to get the properties in the objects inside the grouping.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You have a number of options for unwrapping the types of the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface, the most straightforward being to get the second type parameter from the object's type. That said, it's bit odd that you are passing an `IGrouping<...>` to the method when what you want is to filter on the properties of the _elements_ within each group. It sounds like the design is a little broken and you should be passing a different object. But there's not enough context to really know what the best approach is. There are too many possible answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you will be passing an `IGrouping`, the following should work. However, this way requires that you pass the types of the key and grouped object.

```
    public static void FilterSource<TKey,TElement>(IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> source, string filter)
    {
        //TElement is the type inside the grouping
        var properties = typeof(TElement).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)) .Select(x => x.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, I guess I could use this as an overload. I was writing a solution attempt checking if typeof(T).GetGenericArguments was greater than 1 and if it was was getting the properties for the second element instead of the first. Your solution seems more elegant!